# Converting py into exe, cmd prompt just blink

Tags: python, exe

Hi i want to convert my py into exe, so i download a auto-py-to-exe and convert. After quick process I want to open my exe but when i Click on the exe i just se blink of cmd prompt. I try this on few sample evryone does the same.

```
print("guess a puzlle")

while True:
puzlle = "Malinowy dwór"

s = input("Guess?: ")

if s == puzlle:
         print('Yes')
         break
else:
         print('No')
```

Have this issue on pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe as well.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make sure that your pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe and gevent versions are fully up to date. I am just going to pint out that auto-py-to-exe uses pyinstaller to convert files. If you did not require gevent when you installed auto-py-to-exe then it is a good idea for you to install it from [here](https://pypi.org/project/gevent/). When you open cmd and type auto-py-to-exe you should get a GUI which allows you to select your own options. In the newest version you will see the warning:

[image: auto-py-to-exe warning]

[Read more here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4311).

This may be one of the reasons why your exe is failing. Using an earlier version of python (such as 3.7) may sort your problem out. Your issue may just be that it takes a while to load - it happens on some devices. If you leave your exe running and then the cmd window closes then you have some sort of error that you need to address and that the file shouldn't run in your IDE either.

There is also the possibility that there are some small issues that you wouldn't even think were a problem. If the indent level is wrong then it is possible that your exe will either crash - or will never go down that part of the statement. You must make sure everything is absolutely perfect so that the program can run as smoothly as possible.

I hope I was able to help a bit...